# ios show svg files, zooming and add marks on them

Tags: ios, svg

I have some requirements to do:

1. My app needs to load svg files and display them on screen.
2. Users can zoom in/out the svg files to see more details.
3. Users can add dots/marks on the svg files to highlight the interesting part of the svg file. The location of the dots will be sent to server and be saved in database, so that some other user can read the dots on the same svg files.
4. The dots should be able to adjust their locations to indicate the right place while svgs are zooming.

The following screenshot shows these function from App
[image]

Anyone knows how to do these? Should I load local svg files or load from server and display on webview? How to handle the marks drawing on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not have native support for displaying SVG files, but apparently the browser does, so you might be able to display them in a web view.

A quick google search on "iOS SVG viewer" also found a Github repo called SVGKit:

https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit